React component generator
I am working on a React component meta code generator. I have a bunch of prebuilt React components like <TwoCol>, <Heading>, <Image> etc. These components use named slots ie <TwoCol slot1={<Heading/>} slot2={<Image/>}/>. The props are provided as JSON and can contain different components for the slots, so as to generate different versions of the component.
In a React application (client-side) this all works. But in that case we are rendering the components.
The app we are building is on the server-side (Node) behind an API. It accepts a JSON representation of the component tree and it should return the source code of the newly composed React component.
We are easily able to return HTML by using React.renderToString but how would you approach returning the updated source code of the React component?

Example:
Given the following input
{
  "componentId": "TwoColShell",
  "props": {},
  "slots": [
    {
      "slotId": "slot1",
      "components": [
        {
          "componentId": "Heading",
          "props": {
            "heading": "My Heading"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "slotId": "slot2",
      "components": [
        {
          "componentId": "Image",
          "props": {
            "src": "https://www.example.com/assets/image.png",
            "alt": "alt text"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

And the following components <TwoColShell>, <Heading>, <Image>
import * as React from "react";

export const TwoColShell = (props) => {
  const { slot1, slot2 } = props;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="grid">
        <div>{slot1}</div>
        <div>{slot2}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

import * as React from "react";

const Image = (props) => {
  return <img {...props} />;
};

export { Image };

import * as React from "react";

const Heading = ({ heading, ...props }) => {
  return <h1 {...props}>{heading}</h1>;
};

export { Heading };

Return the source code.
import * as React from "react";
import { Heading } from "./Heading";
import { Image } from "./Image";

export const TwoColShell = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="grid">
        <div>
          <Heading heading="My Heading" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image src="https://www.example.com/assets/image.png" alt="alt text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


You're probably looking for the term hydration.

So I don't want to attach the result to a browser DOM node and render it. I want to generate the updated source code of the component and write that to a file.

Ok, what specific part do strugle with. Generating source code or writing to a file? Alternatively wouldn't it be easier to dynamically do this based on your JSON input?

No writing the file is fine. Thats just to help clarify that I am not "rendering a react component" as most might assume. I want to understand some different approaches to generating the source code of a new react component.
We do accept JSON input, and from that I can build a react component. The current approach is to use React.createElement to build the entire component tree, but the return value from createElement which is a ReactNode, I need to convert this back to source code.

I understand, so you're interested in creating a .js file that contains the component. A common way to handle this is using a simple template engine, just like you might generate a .HTML file. Make sure you get escaping right.

I was hoping to it without using a templating engine, because we already have all the components written in React. Also with a template engine that just uses strings it could easily return uncompilable results, so it would require additional testing of generated components, and we want to generate on demand.

What sort of answer are you hoping for? If you're generating code you'll have to work with strings at some point.
